# Android Jelly Bean help or user manual

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, documentation

Can I get inline help with functionality in my Android device? For example, my good old Nokia had a help feature, with which after selecting an item for a few seconds, it used to display the description and purpose of the selected item.

If this is not possible, where can I find a Jelly Bean user manual or documentation?

Comment: What's the purpose of the manual? I think most of the basic functionalities of the device are quite intuitive.

Comment: some of the features/settings are confusing to the new user.

Comment: which features exactly?

Comment: What model of phone do you have?

Comment: Well, I was expecting some kind of A to Z user manual for android so as to discover the functionalities that I am not aware of instead of particular feature for particular device (of course some features may vary across devices).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you first activate an Android phone, there is a short tutorial that walks you through the home screen, adding icons/widgets to the home screen, navigating the home screen, etc. On stock android, there is also a helpful widget on the homescreen.

For many phones, there is a small booklet (often called the manual) in the box when you purchase the device. These booklets can also be found online, for example some popular Android 4.0 devices: [Galaxy Nexus user guide](https://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//help/hc/pdfs/mobile/AndroidUsersGuide-40-en.pdf), or [Galaxy S3](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201207/20120706131108550/VZW_SCH-i535_English_User_Manual_LG1_F5.pdf), or [HTC Incredible](http://dl3.htc.com/htc_na/user_guides/htc-droid-incredible-verizon-ug.pdf). You can find manuals for your device by browsing the manufacturer's website or googling for "(device name) manual" or "(device name) user guide".

Manufacturer websites also typically have a Knowledge Base, Support Center, etc. For instance, [HTC Support Center for Desire X](http://www.htc.com/www/help/htc-desire-x/) or [Samsung Support for Galaxy Note](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/GT-N8013EAVXAR).

Finally, there are also Android StackExchange and [other Android-related forums](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-android-enthusiast-questions?rq=1) which contain lots of helpful people willing to answer your questions. If you're still unclear on anything specific, ask away!

Answer (score 1):

[Google Support offers some online guides](http://support.google.com/android/). At present, the devices listed under Jelly Bean are:

- Xoom
- Galaxy Nexus
- Nexus S
- Nexus 4
- Nexus 7
- Nexus 10

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [Nexus 7 user guide](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/SNP_2670257_en_v0) in PDF format. Since it was the first device to launch with Jelly Bean and isn't hampered by manufacturer/carrier customizations, it's as close to a pure Jelly Bean user guide as there is.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the [Complete Android Guide](http://completeandroidguide.com/), a PDF/[wiki](http://www.completeguides.net/01_The_Complete_Android_Guide)/book created by long-time Lifehacker editor Kevin Purdy.