# Why can't I copy files between the external & interal SD on an Android 4.2 tablet?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, file-transfer, file-management, documentation

When I insert a micro-SD card into the tablet, I can open the graphical "*file manager*" in the apps and view which files & folders are on the internal-SD and the external-SD. However I can not discover how to copy a file *from* the internal *to* the external SD or vice-versa. The File Manager lets me create a copy of a file in the same folder, but there was no hint given as to how to copy or move a file from one folder or storage medium to another.

The tablet I am trying to work with is apparently a `FAST-TOUCH` (??) which is running Android 4.2.2. I think it may be [this 10" tablet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ECKG0XK), or at least it is very similar to it.

I did not purchase the tablet and I definitely do not have "admin" access. I have tried to locate a user manual, but I do not think one exists. It seems to be rather common for Android devices to come with little or no useful documentation.

I would normally never bother to ask about this since I always considered simple file ops to be very trivial procedures. But I have never used an Android tablet (or phone) before and, frankly, I do **not** find using it to be as intuitive as I think others assume it to be.

### **A Note About Edits**

This question previously focused on asking about documentation. I have stripped most of that out and repurposed the question to ask only about how to do a simple file copy with the File Manager on the tablet.

Before I posted the question I attempted to locate previous questions about basic Android documentation, but failed to find them. For some reason, I only seem to be able to find the questions I am looking for if I first create and post a duplicate question.

I am posting links to the general documentation questions I found below for possible future reference since, frankly, I doubt my ability to find them again.

[Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-android-enthusiast-questions)

[Where can I find a thorough introduction to Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17760/where-can-i-find-a-thorough-introduction-to-android)

[Android Jelly Bean help or user manual](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32894/android-jelly-bean-help-or-user-manual)

Answer (score 1):

I use [Total Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander&hl=nl) for this kind of stuff. You can use the second button in the bottom bar to move files. 
Total Commander lets you open two locations at once, which makes copying between those locations even easier.

Comment: And what would you use if you could not install apps or widgets. I am only a user. I don't have admin access to this tablet. I assume there is a way to copy files, it is just not clear to me how one does this in Android.

Comment: You should be able to install applications on your Android tablet without administrator rights. Do you have `Play Store` on your tablet? If so, you can search Total Commander in the Play Store and hit install. If not, you should be able to download [this](http://ghisler.com/tcandroid2.apk) file and install it on your tablet. Make sure you allow installation of apps from unknown sources in your settings (Go to Settings > Security).

With the `File Manager` app you can try to do a long press on the file you want to copy and choose `copy` and paste with long press at the req. location.

Answer (score 1):

Hi use ES File Explorer File Manager. It is easy to use , and user friendly .

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

X-plore is an easy to use app from Google to transfer files from internal to external cards and back.  I use it regularly.  Go to  play.google.com, use search bar at top, search for X-plore.  You'll see a couple of the other apps mentioned in earlier responses, both of which I occasionally use.